# Parsing OData $filter into SQL Where clause

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, odata

I need to query tables in a legacy database from a Web API server (C#) that uses ODATA.  I have a basic ODBC driver for the legacy database and I only need to support basic filtering at this time (eq, startswith and substringof).  For example:

queryOptions.Filter.RawValue:

```
( (startswith(Name,'Bill'))  and  
(substringof('sunset',Address))  and  
(substringof('7421',Phone)) )
```

Should be converted into something like this (I am only concerned with the WHERE clause here):

```
SELECT CustName, Address1, Address2, ... 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustName like 'Bill%' AND 
  Address1 like '%sunset% AND 
  Phone like '%7421%'
```

I realize that parsing the RawValue is probably not a great idea.

*Does anybody have something similar already written that I can use as a starting point? Or advice on a good, reliable way to accomplish this?*

Comment: See my answer in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36956462/3271357

Comment: I also posted an alternative at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372999/translate-odata-queries-to-sql/42547175#42547175

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply some Regex to the raw value, obtain the matches and apply some logic to make the transformation.
Basically, search the functions with the parameters, remove the function text, get the parameters and transform them into the like clauses.
Something like this:

```
string str = @"( (startswith(Name,'Bill'))  and  
(substringof('sunset',Address))  and  
(substringof('7421',Phone)) )";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"startswith\(([^\)]+)\)");

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = regex.Match(str);

if (match.Success)
{
  string tmp = match.Value;
  string destination = "@field LIKE '@val%'";

  tmp = tmp.Replace( "startswith(","");
  tmp = tmp.Replace( ")","");

  string[] keyvalue = tmp.Split(',');
  string field = keyvalue[0];
  string val = keyvalue[1];

  destination = destination.Replace("@field", field);
  destination = destination.Replace("@val", val.Replace("'",""));
  Console.WriteLine( destination );
}
```

This outputs:

```
Name LIKE 'Bill%'
```

Comment: @epsino316 Thanks, but parsing the raw value using reg ex will probably be a bit fragile (the ODATA query filter is based on whatever the users enter in the UI, including characters that will break the regex unless escaped, etc.).  I was hoping to find a more robust approach (without having to write my own query provider).

Comment: Can't think of anything without it. Probably some commercial transformation tool, or look for an open source specific project in github.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not directly helping OP I keep coming back to this question over the years and have developed another trick you can use if your current schema is close to the legacy database.

> This will only apply if you can create a query that is similar or the same against the EF context, we will be exploiting the Linq to Entity SQL table alias conventions and as such it may be affected by future updates.

1. define an EF query that closely approximates the table structure of your output.
2. use `FilterQueryOption.ApplyTo()` to apply *just the `$filter`* to the approximated query
3. Capture the SQL string from the query
4. Extract the `WHERE` clause from the query
5. Inject the `WHERE` clause into your custom query.

Apart from being tied to the table alias constraints the EF injects, this offers a lot of security and flexibility over using REGEX alone. you might find that you can use regex to further enhance this output, however the OData parser will already validate and sanitise the URL expression into valid SQL syntax, including transposing the expression into SQL function calls.

> The following is based on EF6 and OData v4, so the URL syntax is a bit different, but the same concept should apply to previous versions of ODataLib as well.

- *`CustomDTO` is a custom class, not defined in the EF DbContext model.*
- `Customer` *IS* defined in the EF DbContext, it has similar fields to the legacy database

```
/// <summary>Return a list of customer summaries for a given Account</summary>
[EnableQuery, HttpGet]
public IQueryable<CustomDTO> Customers([FromODataUri] int key, ODataQueryOptions<CustomDTO> _queryOptions)
{
    // The custom query we want to apply to the legacy database.
    // NOTE: If the fields are identical to the current DbContext, then we don't have to go this far.
    // We MUST alias the table to match the generated SQL
    string sql = "SELECT CustName, IsNull(Address1,'') + IsNull(Address2,'') as Address, Phone " + 
                 "FROM Customers AS [Extent1]" + 
                 "WHERE AccountId = @AccountId";
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_queryOptions.Filter?.RawValue))
    {
        var criteriaQuery = from x in db.Customers
                            select new CustomDTO
                            {
                                Name = CustName,
                                Address = Address1 + Address2
                                Phone = Phone
                            };
        var modifiedQuery = _queryOptions.Filter.ApplyTo(criteriaQuery, new ODataQuerySettings({ EnableConstantParameterization = false });
        string modifiedSql = modifiedQuery.ToString();
        modifiedSql = modifiedSql.Substring(modifiedSql.LastIndexOf("WHERE ") + 5);
        sql += $" AND ({modifiedSql})";
    }

    var customers = aDifferentContext.Database.SqlQuery<CustomDTO>(sql, new SqlParameter("@AccountId", key)).ToList();
    return customers.AsQueryable();
}
```

- *An alternative to using the alias `[Extent1]` in our custom query would be to use string replacement, but this works well enough.*
- `EnableConstantParameterization` was deliberately disabled, to inline the filter values, instead of having to track and inject the SqlParameter for each filter argument. It similifies the code and is already sanitised to a degree. Its up to you to put in the extra effort if this does not satisfy your security concerns.
- You will notice I filtered to the *LAST* `WHERE` clause in the query, that is because if this query involved projections and the caller tried to apply a filter to one of the secondary extents (joined result sets) then EF will optimise the query by filtering the sub query, rather than applying the filters all at the end. There are ways around this or to work with it, for now lets stick to a simple example.

#### SQL Generated by `modifiedQuery`:

*URL:* `~/OData/Accounts(1102)/Customers?$filter=startswith(Name, 'Bill') and contains(Address, 'sunset') and contains(Phone, '7421')`

*Filter.RawValue:* `startswith(Name, 'Bill') and contains(Address, 'sunset') and contains(Phone, '7421')`

```sql
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CustName] AS [Name], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Address1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[Address1] END + CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Address2] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[Address2] END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Phone] AS [Phone]
    FROM  [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[CustName] LIKE 'Bill%') 
      AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Address1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[Address1] END 
              + CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Address2] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[Address2] END 
           LIKE N'%sunset%') 
      AND ([Extent1].[Phone] LIKE '%7421%')
```

The final SQL that gets executed:

```sql
SELECT CustName as Name, IsNull(Address1,'') + IsNull(Address2,'') as Address, Phone 
  FROM  [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE AccountId = @AccountId AND (([Extent1].[CustName] LIKE 'Bill%') 
      AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Address1] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[Address1] END 
              + CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Address2] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[Address2] END 
           LIKE N'%sunset%') 
      AND ([Extent1].[Phone] LIKE '%7421%'))
```

#### Class Definitions

```
public class CustomDTO
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Address { get;set; }
    public string Phone { get;set; }
} 

public class Customer
{
    public int AccountId { get;set; }
    public string CustName { get;set; }
    public string Address1 { get;set; }
    public string Address2 { get;set; }
    public string Phone { get;set; }
}
```

---

I use this trick mostly when optimising complex Linq expressions that return DTO structures that can be implemented with much simpler SQL than EF ca produce. What was a traditional EF query is replaced with a raw SQL query in the form of `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql, parameters)`

In this example I used a different EF DbContext, but once you have the SQL script, you should be able to run that however you need to.